# Как узнать есть ли в строке деление на ноль

Tags: php, javascript, html

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть строка,которую вводит пользователь в инпут,из этого инпута через пхп считаю эту строку.Как можно сделать вывод сообщения,если в строке присутствует деление на ноль.
Заранее благодарю за ответ
Пример:
"2+2/0" Сообщение "Деление на ноль"
"5/0+1" Сообщение "Деление на ноль"

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = [
  "2+2/0",
  "5/0+1"
];

foreach($arr as $val){
  if(strpos($val, '/0') !== false)
    print "$val: Деление на ноль!\n";
}
```

?

Comment: господе, почему просто не `strpos`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а пробелы?

Comment: @Other У меня калькулятор,состоящий из кнопок,то есть человек вводит цифры путем,нажатия кнопок,поэтому пробелы невозможны)

Comment: @tweeker, А зачем тогда строка? Динамически отслеживаете кто на что делит и выводите ошибку при надобности.

Comment: @Other к сожалению,у меня не настолько прокачен скилл. Единственное,до чего я допер,эт проверять строку)